# $[0,5]$ partitioned in $n$ equal subintervals. $x_i$ chosen in $i^{th}$ subinterval for each $i$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{4x-11}{n}$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, summation

### Question

The interval $[0,5]$ is partitioned into $n$ equal subintervals and a number $x_i$ is chosen arbitrarily in the $i^{th}$ subinterval for each $i$. **Determine**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4x-11}{n}$$

As intermediate steps, **find**.

- $\Delta x_i$
  [I solved it as $\frac{5}{n}$]
- $f(x)$
  [I solved it as $\frac{4x-11}{5}$]

I found answer to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4x-11}{n}$ as $-1$

### My Approach

There are $5$ intervals, hence $n = 5$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4x-11}{n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4x-11}{5}$$

Thus, it reduces to
$$\int_{a}^n \frac{4x - 11}{n}dx,$$
where
$a = 0$ and $n = 5$

$= \int_{0}^5 \frac{4x - 11}{5}dx$

$= \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^5 (4x - 11)dx$

$= \frac{1}{5}[2x^2 - 11x]_0^5$

$= \frac{50-55}{5}$

on solving we get $-1$

### Image Attachment [though typed using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)]

- Snapshot of [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxS5.jpg)
- My [Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqaA4.jpg)

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Please remove all of the image links from your posting, and express all of the Math, directly in your posting, via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).